# Did Mirai Kuriyama really rebuild her body, or what really happened to it?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

Mirai's body vanished/consumed/disintegrated during the battle vs Kyoukai no Kanata, then there is this version of her in Akihito's "dream world" that dissolves on-screen, then months(?) later she is alive in flesh *and blood* (pun intended).

So, what happened?  Was her blood control so high that she willed herself back into a physical body, or is it some [Applied Phlebotinum](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum) fiat?

Comment: Actually, reading the question title after posting it, the spoiler warning is useless; the very title spoils it big time.

Comment: Perhaps you could amend it to a request for an explanation of the anime's ending? On a more relevant note, the series is getting two movies, one of which was released March 14 and the other which will be released April 25. The first movie is a recap of the series while the second takes place a year later - those might end up answering your question. I'd suggest you read the light novels (the original medium), but they haven't been translated so you're out of luck if you can't read Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is sort of a zombie, sorry, and purely speculation on my part, but I think it went like so:

Mirai initially vanished by absorbing KnK into her body, so she was intermingled with it from the beginning... but she was never really dead.

With KnK exerting all its power to combat her blood, another dimension is created, but their existence in that world is a supernatural manifestation of virtually incorporeal beings.  KnK has to use all focus fighting her blood which is a constant assailant on its very core, and somehow this is created.  Though the exact reason this phenomenon occurs and the function thereof is not crystal clear, it's fairly tertiary to this point, so I'll avoid the digression.

After the battle, KnK's not as strong as it once was, since it took a pretty bad pounding.  Weakened (despite outside interference, to said party's astonishment), Aki is able to subdue KnK entirely having learned to control a mere fraction of KnK's full power, and he absorbs it back into his body (which actually includes Mirai as well).  Since it's Aki's force of will now actively taking control of it, rather than just fighting in the same vessel, Mirai vanishes because as KnK is no longer the one willing the alternate dimension where she'd manifest into existence.  She's really still inside KnK, which Aki absorbed and has at least partial control of.

Later, his extreme desire to see her again, and to relive his memories of the first meeting, are so potent that he actually exercises some of KnK's power subconsciously, extracting her from it and placing her right where he most wanted her to be.  He knew what he was thinking at the time, and rushed to the place he had seen her in his mind, knowing that the ring vanishing meant she had been reunited with it, as was his most profound desire.

Could be wrong though.  Take it or leave it :)

Comment: This is not a forum, there is no such thing as a zombie question. Answers on SE sites are gold, its never too late to dig gold. You put your point quite convincing.

Answer (score 1):

In *Mirai-hen*, Akihito contemplates the matter (around 7 minutes into the movie).

> Akihito wonders whether Mirai's memory loss was the doing of the KnK. I take this to imply that Mirai being there in the first place may *also* have been the doing of the KnK.
>
>  This explanation seems consistent with what we learn about the KnK during *Mirai-hen*: that it is, in fact, some sort of "gate" between the world of humans and the world of youmu. That is, it seems entirely plausible that the KnK could have transported Mirai from wherever-she-was and put her back into the human world.
>
>  The motives of the KnK in doing so seem unclear to me, though (insofar as the KnK is sentient enough to *have* motives) - Mirai's lineage's sole purpose in life was to destroy the KnK, so I find it curious that it would choose to be useful Mirai in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that since the Dreamshade *Kyoukai no Kanata* was absorbed back into Akihito Kanbara's body, he might have had some unconscious control over the other dimension that the Dreamshade created, and since he wanted Mirai Kuriyama so badly, he might have brought her back from that dimension. After all, it was his dream world.

Comment: I will assume that is speculation on your part, or do you have any sources?

Comment: Yes,it was speculation on my part but the other possibilities are not so convincing.First,she has used up all her blood for defeating the dreamshade,she doesn't have a body to regenerate new blood.Second,Akihito really missed her,he even kept her ring with him,that ring disappeared from his hand.Now,if Mirai Kuriyama had appeared,how would she have taken that ring from him without him noticing.Thus,I thought this would be plausible.

Comment: Wathched the entire series again,Akihito thinks in the end that his feelings got through to her or it was in fate or it was because of everything that Kuriyama-san did.Maybe, it was willpower after all.

Answer (score 0):

It's a crap one, but I'd like to put the thought out there that the writer probably thought that her rebuilding her body could be easily explained by his over load on food at the shop, she could have easily felt his feelings and decided it would be better to live, the one in the dimension had a different outfit on, I'm willing to bet that was the writers way of letting us know that the real one was already out making an effort to rebuild her body, after all she could replenish her blood very fast after only one meal, why not be able to create a flimsy body as the construct and him fought so that she could eat and rebuild herself? Not such a big plot hole when you analyze the capabilities of the characters and the clues put into the fight build up. More eating for extra nutrition, and a different version of her in the dimension then what was seen before. Incredibly well planned out if you can find the bread crumbs to come to the most apparent conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

she said that the original body of herself was long gone, at that point it was only her spirit fighting the battle with the KnK though it did show I believe that she was bound up somewhere where that *whatever he was* had arrived, though I could be wrong on that.

theres tons of controversy as to exactly what happened, but because of the words she implied I believe she was never physically inside of the KnK but her love had created the dummy of Aki. which to me is beyond strange and I almost thought she was supposed to kill it since it was *his* memories in a way.

some of it seemed rushed with sending everyone here and there and maybe its just the fact that I read sub, but I couldn't comprehend the translation in some parts which could be faulty to the difference is language translation.

when the ring disappeared from his hand and ended up bringing him up to the roof top of the school I immediately suspected that he was causing his own illusion, because even if she *did* come back and had reembodied herself, she would not have been able to just make a ring magically reappear from the hand of her love to her pinky. then you'd have to think "Why didn't she appear with her glasses as well?"

its sad to think that she did in fact parish in the end, however that's how it appears to have fallen.

the anime in which the girls parish seem to be the only kind of anime I can find lately without even knowing that's what I'm watching until I'm engrossed, I'm running out of anime options considering I read and watch too many mangas and anime.

this is my interpretation of how things fell, looks like Aki went insane :'(

ill have to watch the movie(s)